# writing model method tests using minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I use mini-test for testing framework. I try to write model tests.

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :provider, type:String
  field :user_id, type:String
  field :name, type:String

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |person|
      person.provider = auth["provider"]
      person.user_id = auth["uid"]
      #user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    end
  end

  def self.find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)
    where(provider: provider, user_id: uid).first
  end

end
```

Above is my person model. I want to write a test that controls if person has "create_with_omniauth method" or not.

How can I write this test. I wait your ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this you can use [assert_respond_to](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_respond_to).

A complete example:

```rb
class PersonTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_responds_to_create_with_omniauth
     assert_respond_to(Person, :create_with_omniauth)
  end
end
```

My personal opinion would be to test the behaviour of the method instead of asserting whether it exists or not, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually, I think like you. But my text leader wants all tests. Also, I want to ask one more question. How can I test behaviour. For example, for "find_by_provider_and_uid(provider, uid)" method. How can I test this? If you give me an idea, i will be happy. Thanks again.

Comment: That could be accomplished by setting up two or more fixtures/factories and then make sure that when you send the message `find_by_provider_and_uid` with a certain provider and uid, you get the fixture/factory back.

If my answer helped you out, don't be shy to mark it as "the right answer".